# How do I read data from the web based on the number of rows

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-webbrowser

How do I read data from the web based on the number of rows.
Example: I want to read only 2 rows from a 30-row table

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="https://weather.day.az/az/"
response=requests.get(url)
icerik=response.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(icerik,"html.parser")
hava=soup.find_all("",{"class":"location_name"})
derece=soup.find_all("",{"class":"weather_factical"})
for temp,weather in zip(hava,derece):
  temp=temp.text
  temp = temp.replace("\n", "")
  weather=weather.text
  weather=weather.replace("\n","")
  print(temp)
  print(weather)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a counter variable and count the times you loop has iterated, like so:

```py
for i,(temp,weather) in enumerate(zip(hava,derece)):
    temp=temp.text
    temp = temp.replace("\n", "")
    weather=weather.text
    weather=weather.replace("\n","")
    print(temp)
    print(weather)
    if i==1:
        break
```

The above code will print the top 2 values.